# How to append list of values to a column of list in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, merge

I want to append list values to column of list in dataframe. Lets say, I have two dataframes `first_df` and `second_df` and want `expected` as follow.

Eg.

```
first_df =
|  date | value
| 01/01 | [1,2]
| 01/02 | nan
| 01/03 | [3]
| 01/04 | [2]
| 01/05 | nan
| 01/01 | nan

second_df = 
|  date | value
| 01/01 | [2,3]
| 01/02 | [1,2]
| 01/03 | [1,2]
| 01/04 | nan
| 01/05 | [1,2]
| 01/06 | nan

expected = 
|  date | value
| 01/01 | [1,2,3]
| 01/02 | [1,2]
| 01/03 | [1,2,3]
| 01/04 | [2]
| 01/05 | [1,2]
| 01/06 | nan
```

Comment: `pd.concat([df1.explode('date'), df2.explode('date')]).groupby('date')['value'].agg(lambda x: list(set(x)))`.